# AppVeyor build script file downloads fail intermittently

Tags: qt, curl, qt-creator, appveyor

I am currently using AppVeyor to build a small Qt Creator plugin. As part of the build, I am downloading the Qt Creator sources and install package.

This used to work fine, but at some point it stopped working. Now, sometimes the first download succeeds, but at least one of the downloads never succeed.

I have tried both the installed `curl` binary, as well as the `appveyor DownloadFile` command, but they both fail.

The `curl` error is as follows:

```
curl: (18) transfer closed with 31294991 bytes remaining to read
```

The `appveyor DownloadFile` command does not generate an error, but unpacking the resulting archive fails instead:

```
ERROR: qt-bin.7z
qt-bin.7z
Open ERROR: Can not open the file as [7z] archive
ERRORS:
Unexpected end of archive
```

An example of a failing build can be seen here
https://ci.appveyor.com/project/jesperhh/teamfoundation/build/3.6.49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try enabling proxy - this should help: http://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/http-proxy

Comment: Perhaps a link should be added from https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/download-file to http://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/http-proxy